# BUILD FAILED hybris ant clean all after taking a code update

Tags: java, ant, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I am using SAP Commerce 2205 on Ubantu with Java (SAP Machine) version 17 and eveytime I run ant clean all the build fails with the error mentioned below. I am able to do the setup for the first time and all works fine, no error.
But once I take a code update and the run ant clean all, the build fails. I have tried multiple times with a new setup but everytime the build fails with the same error. Here is my config and part of the error log:

```
SAP Commerce 2205
openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment SapMachine (build 17.0.5+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM SapMachine (build 17.0.5+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

[delete] Deleting directory /home/ccc/v11/core-customize/hybris/temp/hybris/bofs
   [script] [To redirect Truffle log output to a file use one of the following options:
   [script] * '--log.file=<path>' if the option is passed using a guest language launcher.
   [script] * '-Dpolyglot.log.file=<path>' if the option is passed using the host Java launcher.
   [script] * Configure logging using the polyglot embedding API.]
   [script] [engine] WARNING: The polyglot context is using an implementation that does not support runtime compilation.
   [script] The guest application code will therefore be executed in interpreted mode only.
   [script] Execution only in interpreted mode will strongly impact the guest application performance.
   [script] For more information on using GraalVM see https://www.graalvm.org/java/quickstart/.
   [script] To disable this warning the '--engine.WarnInterpreterOnly=false' option or use the '-Dpolyglot.engine.WarnInterpreterOnly=false' system property.
```

Build fail Logs:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/ccc/v11/core-customize/hybris/bin/platform/build.xml:13: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ccc/v11/core-customize/hybris/bin/platform/resources/ant/compiling.xml:95: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ccc/v11/core-customize/hybris/bin/platform/resources/ant/compiling.xml:207: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ccc/v11/core-customize/hybris/bin/platform/resources/ant/util.xml:13: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ccc/v11/core-customize/hybris/bin/platform/resources/ant/compiling.xml:209: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ccc/v11/core-customize/hybris/bin/platform/resources/ant/util.xml:142: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ccc/v11/core-customize/hybris/bin/modules/backoffice-framework/backoffice/buildcallbacks.xml:469: The following error occurred while executing this line:
**/home/ccc/v11/core-customize/hybris/bin/modules/backoffice-framework/backoffice/buildcallbacks.xml:510: TypeError: invokeMember (setProperty) on org.apache.tools.ant.Project@8923ce failed due to: Unknown identifier: setProperty
    at <js> :program(<eval>:3:15-74)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:379)
    at com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine.GraalJSScriptEngine.eval(GraalJSScriptEngine.java:458)**
    at com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine.GraalJSScriptEngine.eval(GraalJSScriptEngine.java:426)
    at java.scripting/javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.evaluateScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:150)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.optional.JavaxScriptRunner.executeScript(JavaxScriptRunner.java:82)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.Script.execute(Script.java:53)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at java.base/java.util.Vector.forEach(Vector.java:1365)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:67)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "once I take a code update"?

Comment: I mean we have hybris development in progress which is deployed on git. So when I take a code update from git and then run ant clean all, the build fails.

Comment: Does it works with ant clean customize all?

Comment: No. ant clean customize all fails with the same error.

Comment: what is the java version that you are using?

Comment: openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18 LTS      
OpenJDK Runtime Environment SapMachine (build 17.0.5+8-LTS)     
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM SapMachine (build 17.0.5+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: please check any alteration done in gradle version,so before doing any other command please try "and customize"

Answer (score -1):

You need to source setantenv.sh script  =>  .  ./setantenv.sh

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.